# Can't display my custom suggestion using SearchView

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, searchview, search-suggestion

I'm using a SearchView and I have added the search feature (that works) and now I'm trying to add a custom suggestion. The provider is created but when i type something query() is never called for some reasons.

Where am I wrong?

Here my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chefme.chefme">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.permission-group.MICROPHONE"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
            android:name=".RecipeIngredientTabs.SuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs.SuggestionProvider">
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".Startup"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RecipeIngredientTabs.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".RecipeStep"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recipe_steps"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RecipePreview.RecipePreview"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recipe_preview"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ShoppingList.ShoppingList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_shopping_list"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings.Diets"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_diets"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Favorite.FavoriteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favorite"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ownRecipesCamera.TakePicture"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_take_picture"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings.Credits"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_credits"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here my Provider:

```
package com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import DBUtility.Data;


public class SuggestionProvider extends ContentProvider{
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        System.out.println("Creation Provider");
        return true;
    }
@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    String query = uri.getLastPathSegment().toLowerCase();  //Dovrebbe essere chiamato tramite searchable.xml
    System.out.println("write: "+ query);

    String[] columns = new String[]{"_ID", "SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1", "SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1", "SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA"};
    MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);

    Object[] row = new Object[]{0, Data.currentIngredients.get(0).getName(), Data.currentIngredients.get(0).getImage(), "Gigi"};
    cursor.addRow(row);

    return cursor;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] strings) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String s, String[] strings) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Here my searchable.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/action_search" >
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs.SuggestionProvider
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.Intent.action.VIEW" >
</searchable>
```

Here my main:

```
package com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.chefme.chefme.NavbarActivity;
import com.chefme.chefme.R;

import java.io.File;

import DBUtility.Data;

public class Main extends NavbarActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter selectorPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private Toast backtoast;

    // Storage Permissions
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.replaceContentLayout(R.layout.main_content, super.CONTENT_LAYOUT_ID);

        verifyDirectoryExists();

        verifyStoragePermissions(this);

        handleIntent(getIntent());

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, //host activity
                drawer, //drawerLayout object
                toolbar, //nav drawer icon to replace
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        selectorPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(selectorPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Data.active_main = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Data.active_main = false;
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
            if(backtoast!=null&&backtoast.getView().getWindowToken()!=null) {
                finish();
            } else {
                backtoast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                backtoast.show();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            System.out.println("Searched: " + query);
        }
        else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) { //Intent partito da SuggestionProvider
            String query = intent.getDataString();
            System.out.println("Suggested: " + query);
        }

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //                              TAB SELECTOR FUNCTIONS
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            if(position == 0)
                return new TabFragmentIngredients();
            if(position == 1)
                return new TabFragmentRecipes();
            else
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.name_ingredients_hint);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.name_recipes_hint);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //                                     MENU FUNCTIONS
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings: showOrderbyDialog();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showOrderbyDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        OrderByDialog orderbyDialogDialog = new OrderByDialog();
        orderbyDialogDialog.show(fm, "");
    }

    public static void verifyDirectoryExists(){

        String folder_main = "GnammyRecipes";

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Pictures/", folder_main);

        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
    }


    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to change to this

```
android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs.SuggestionProvider
```

to

```
android:searchSuggestAuthority="@string/application_package_name"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
```

Also you are missing meta-data tag

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs.YOURSEARCHACTIVITY" >
            </meta-data>
```

Refer this link 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: I tried that and nothing change. I have already followed that guide step by step and it seem everything is correct.

Comment: does it throw any error in log? Please add debug point into your search activity class to see if it reaches tr

Comment: The only error i get is this: "08-25 12:30:21.786 2264-2264/com.chefme.chefme E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length" but I don't think is related with this, what do you think?

Comment: I tested that and query() is never called, the SuggestionProvider is found because the constructor is automatically called but query() doesn't.

Comment: <provider
            android:name=".RecipeIngredientTabs.SuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs.SuggestionProvider">
        </provider>   change authorites to match your packagename and name to complete path?

Comment: Can you please change provider name to complete path and authorities to complete package name?

Comment: Something like this? 
<provider
android:name="com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs.SuggestionProvider"
android:authorities="com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs.SuggestionProvider">
        </provider>

Comment: try  <provider android:name="com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs.Suggest‌​ionProvider" android:authorities="com.chefme.chefme.RecipeIngredientTabs"> </provider>

Comment: Tried and still got nothing. I really don't know what I'm missing